# Suitable phrase for an easy journey?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I want an attractive suitable phrase for describing an easy journey.
For example,

> The journey was a piece of cake.

I think the sentence sounds absurd hence I need something more appealing and fancy.

Comment: The trip was **plain sailing**.

Comment: *I think the sentence sounds absurd* To a native speaker it sounds perfectly fine. You should accept that not all idioms will sound sensible when translated into your language.

Comment: _To a native speaker it sounds perfectly fine._ To this native speaker, it sounds faintly absurd ... a metaphor better replaced. 'Plain sailing' _might_ work, but sounds tongue-in-cheek if not literal.

Answer (score 1):

A common idiomatic expression is:

> The journey was a breeze.

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/23033?rskey=siwEAf&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)* definition of *breeze* for this sense:

> *slang.* Something easy to achieve, handle, etc. Originally *U.S.*

Answer (score 0):

> jaunt
> a short excursion or journey for pleasure

Comment: What's the source of this definition?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add. [jaunt: Oxford Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=jaunt+definition&rlz=1C1GCEA_enPH884PH884&oq=jaunt&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i271l2.3285j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Jaunt also has an archaic meaning of  "A wearisome journey". https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jaunt . One moderator told in a comment to another question about "gaps in the dictionary world". Better to search multiple dictionaries, one which may be "Wiktionary", it gives nice etymological explanation.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

A **walk in the park** is "something that is very easy to do, and usually pleasant" according to [Cambridge dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/walk-in-the-park).

It's not always used of journeys - Cambridge gives the example sentence "He's used to hard physical work - this is a walk in the park to him" - but it certainly could be.

Comment: 'The train journey through the Rhone Valley was a walk in the park' sounds like an inappropriate choice of metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Smooth sailing. Straight sailing, plain sailing. easy sailing. A breeze. Straightforward. There was nothing to it. No sweat. A cinch. A waltz.
If nothing works you can be metaphorical.
The trip was like a walk in the park.

Answer (score -1):

Cruise ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cruise)), Sojourn ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sojourn)) are everyday words adequate for the purpose. Some fancy words may be

Junket ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/junket))  A pleasure-trip; a journey made for feasting or enjoyment, now especially a trip made ostensibly for business but which entails merrymaking or entertainment.

Gallivant ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gallivant)) To roam about for pleasure without any definite plan. To flirt, to romance.

Outing ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/outing)) A pleasure trip or excursion. (Agreed it is not a fancy word :))